# How to stop long words/phrases from changing the position of the container?

Tags: html, css

It's pretty hard to word. Let me know if I explained correctly.

[image: external image]

But as you can see in the image "Bites" is clearly a part of the *li* tag but it is not highlighted when inspected. It also creates a new line which messes up the symmetry of the grid. How do I have it break on a new line and also keep the container intact? I've tried both **max-height** and **max-Width**, **line-height**, **word-wrap** does nothing.

https://jsfiddle.net/fvruayno/

EDIT: HTML snippet

```html
    <ul class="categories-panels>
    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>M</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Almond Something</li>
            <li>Ale Sauce</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>N</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Almond Something</li>
            <li>Ale Sauce</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>O</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Almond Something</li>
            <li>Ale Sauce</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>P</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Pork Buns</li>
            <li>Pretzel, Hershey & M&M Bites</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>Q</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Almond Something</li>
            <li>Ale Sauce</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="recipe-letter">
        <h3>R</h3>
        <ul class="recipe-alphabetically">
            <li>Almond Something</li>
            <li>Ale Sauce</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```css
#categories-panels {
  margin: auto auto;
  height: 1300px;
}

#categories-panels .recipe-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#categories .recipe-alphabetically  {
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

#categories-panels .recipe-letter li {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#categories-panels img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some of your code? Or add it to a jsfiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `vertical-align: top;` to the `#categories-panels .recipe-letter` selector.